# Array error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array with the format `province;capital`.

```
provArray = new String[] { "Alberta;Edmonton", "British Columbia;Victoria", "Manitoba;Winnipeg", "New Brunswick:Fredericton",
            "Newfoundland and Labrador;St.John's", "Nova Scotia;Halifax", "Ontario;Toronto", "Prince Edward Island;Charlottetown",
            "Quebec;Quebec City", "Saskatchewan;Regina", "Northwest Territories;Yellowknife", "Nunavut;Iqaluit", "Yukon;Whitehorse",
            "Alabama;Montgomery", "Alaska;Juneau", "Arizona;Phoenix", "Arkansas;Little Rock", "California;Sacramento", "Colorado;Denver",
            "Connecticut;Hartford"};
```

Then I have a for loop that separates the provinces from the capital (before and after the ";"). Yet for some reason, I get the error, `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1`.

```
for(int k = 0; k < bonusArray.length; k++){
    String[] split = bonusArray[k].split(";");
    String prov = split[0];
    String cap = split[1];

    if(prov.equals(answer)){
       bonusAnswer = cap;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Edit: Fixed, I had accidentally put `:` instead of `;` for one of my array items.

Comment: Consider that this isn't the best way to store this data: define a class `Province`, which stores the name and capital as separate fields, that you initialize like `new Province("Alberta", "Edmonton")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are values in the array which don't have `;` (semicolon), such as `New Brunswick:Fredericton`

so this code

`String[] split = bonusArray[k].split(";");` gives an array of length = 1

and this causes the exception `String cap = split[1];` because you can only access `split[0]` (remember length = 1).

So, you have to make sure every element in the array have `;` or you check the length of the `split` variable before accessing their values.

Comment: e.g. `"New Brunswick:Fredericton"`.

Comment: @AndyTurner exactly!

Comment: thank you for that! Didn't realize, that seems to have fixed it!

Comment: @Revo you're welcome. Great you solved the problem! Remember to [up-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all answers which helped you and [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one for future readers to find these posts useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in "New Brunswick:Fredericton", needs a semi-colon vs a regular colon

Comment: thank you for that! Didn't realize, that seems to have fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
 String[] split = bonusArray[k].split(";");
```

You are simply assuming, you will always get `split` variable with 2 elements. In this case your input has some elements which don't return 2 elements upon split, `split()` not really returning 2 elements, which is why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Always check for "array length" before accessing it's elements at specified index.

EDIT:
"New Brunswick:Fredericton" calling `split(";")` on this string will not return 2 elements.

Comment: Which don't return two elements for instance?

Answer (score 0):

"New Brunswick:Fredericton" contains no ";" .
Try to embed the split() and the [0], [1] part in a try-catch block, to ensure that no OutOfBoundsException occours.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with multiple ways but best approach is to use `split.length-1` instead of giving hard coded value as index. By using this, you will never get this exception even when array length is 1.

```
for(int k = 0; k < bonusArray.length; k++){
    String[] split = bonusArray[k].split(";");
    String prov = split[0];
    String cap = split[split.length-1];

    if(prov.equals(answer)){
       bonusAnswer = cap;
    }
}
```